# Profiling Oracle 10g database JVM

Tags: java, database, oracle, stored-procedures, profiling

We are using Java Stored Procedures on Oracle 10g database. I want to profile the Java Stored Procedures using a Java Profiling tool like JProfiler. How do i do it?

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to call dbms_java.start_jmx_agent() in the session that is calling the java stored procedures. This allows you to connect to the session with jconsole and jvisualvm.

This is documented in Oracle® Database Java Developer's Guide 11g Release 2 (11.2) -> Java Applications on Oracle Database -> Managing Your Applications using JMX.

From oracle forum

http://cn.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2202067

**Unluckily, this is a new feature in 11g.**

**Enabling and Starting JMX in a Session**

Oracle Database 11g release 1 (11.1) introduced a new role JMXSERVER and a new procedure dbms_java.start_jmx_agent to support JMX in the database. The JMXSERVER role is granted specific Java permissions that enable you to start and run MBeanServer and JMX agent in a session. The procedure dbms_java.start_jmx_agent starts the agent in a specific session that generally remains active for the duration of the session. Perform the following to enable and start JMX:

See here for official oracle documents.
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/java.112/e10588/chtwo.htm#CHDFAJIG

Comment: Is there similar options available for Oracle 10g JVM?

Comment: No ,unluckily, it's a new feature in 11g. Without this feature, I think you are not possible to use JMX to profile JVM.